# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in RecyclerView for JellyBean devices

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-recyclerview

I am making an app which supports from API 16 to API 22. I am using RecyclerView to display item list. My code for the layout is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/default_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_icon_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sd"
        android:tint="@color/storage_image_tint" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawer_item_label_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/drawer_item_label_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/s_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textColor="@color/storage_label_selector" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/s_stat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
            android:textColor="@color/storage_stat_selector"
            android:textSize="@dimen/storage_stat_text" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/s_progress"
            style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/storage"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/storage" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This code works fine in API 21 and 22 but when I launch my app in API 16 (JellyBean), My logcat shows the following error.

```
07-27 05:58:42.115  11590-11596/? E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
07-27 05:58:42.487  11590-11590/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.zaeron.filexplorer.Adapter$Storage.onCreateViewHolder(Adapter.java:84)
            at com.zaeron.filexplorer.Adapter$Storage.onCreateViewHolder(Adapter.java:30)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5062)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4368)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4278)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1947)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1359)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1322)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:556)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2673)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2971)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1438)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:931)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallba
```

I am trying to figure this out but I'm not getting how to solve this. BTW I'm new to Android.

EDIT:
My Code for RecyclerView

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/sRecyclerViewContainer"
        style="@style/StorageRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/sRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

</FrameLayout>
```

EDIT: 
I found the problem in my code. Actually nothing is wrong in recyclerView but this recyclerView displays all storages in the device. But when I run it on jellybean most probably there is a problem fetching internal storage of the device. So can anybody help me how do I find internal storage in JellyBean

I use `Environment. getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get storage directory

Comment: Have you added     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
to your gradle..?

Comment: Yes. all compile statements are alright. And works fine in Lollipop

Comment: I am unabel to see where you added RecyclerView. post that too

Comment: Added RecyclerView code

Comment: I just tried your code with sample app its working perfectly. there is no Exception. give a try by removing  style="@style/StorageRecyclerView" in layout. is not then post your java code too with that style

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created drawable or any resource that is in v21 directory. make sure that you have each resource in default resource directory also so when ever you are in lower version you app can use that default resource.

Comment: All drawables are in default directory as I checked again

Comment: did you check values also?

Comment: Values are also in default folder

Answer (score -1):

Your Layout Should be :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And your code:

```
  RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
  RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: I dont know  why you Vote it Down, try this, and then vote it down.